# Symfony 5.4 Embed a Collection of Forms

Tags: symfony, collections, many-to-many

I have to embed a collection into forms. I folowed this :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

But when i try to persist my article object, the added sources are not persisted...

I hope my english is not too poor to be clear in this question

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SourcesRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
u


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SourcesRepository::class)]
class Sources
{
    use TitleTrait;
    use DescriptionTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

     #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Sources::class, mappedBy: 'Aliment')]
    private Collection $Aliment;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Aliment = new ArrayCollection();
       
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Aliment>
     */
    public function getAliment(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Aliment;
    }

    public function addAliment(Aliment $aliment): self
    {
        if (!$this->Aliment->contains($aliment)) {
            $this->Aliment->add($aliment);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAliment(Aliment $aliment): self
    {
        $this->Aliment->removeElement($aliment);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

my Aliment entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AlimentRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AlimentRepository::class)]
class Aliment
{
   
    
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $joules = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $calories = null;

     #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $glycemic_index = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $glycemic_load = null;


     #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Sources::class, mappedBy: 'Aliment', cascade: ['persist'])]
    private Collection $sources;

    


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sources = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getJoules(): ?float
    {
        return $this->joules;
    }

    public function setJoules(?float $joules): self
    {
        $this->joules = $joules;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCalories(): ?float
    {
        return $this->calories;
    }

    public function setCalories(?float $calories): self
    {
        $this->calories = $calories;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGlycemicIndex(): ?float
    {
        return $this->glycemic_index;
    }

    public function setGlycemicIndex(?float $glycemic_index): self
    {
        $this->glycemic_index = $glycemic_index;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGlycemicLoad(): ?float
    {
        return $this->glycemic_load;
    }

    public function setGlycemicLoad(?float $glycemic_load): self
    {
        $this->glycemic_load = $glycemic_load;

        return $this;
    } 

   

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Sources>
     */
    public function getSources(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sources;
    }

    public function addSource(Sources $source): self
    {
        if (!$this->sources->contains($source)) {
            $this->sources->add($source);
            $source->addAliment($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSource(Sources $source): self
    {
        if ($this->sources->removeElement($source)) {
            $source->removeAliment($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

In my controller

```
#[Route('/creation', name : 'ajout')]
    public function ajout(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $aliment = new Aliment();
        $image = new Images();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(AlimentFormType::class, $aliment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                       
            $entityManager->persist($aliment);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('aliment_index');
        }  
        return $this->render('aliment/add.html.twig', [
            'AlimentForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

my vue

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} Ajout d'un Aliment {% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <section class="container">
        <h1 class="h3 m-3 font-weight- text-center">Ajout d'un Aliment</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-6">
                {{ form_start(AlimentForm) }}
                    {{ form_row(AlimentForm.title) }}
                    {{ form_row(AlimentForm.joules) }}
                    {{ form_row(AlimentForm.calories) }}
                   
                </div>
                <div class="text-center col-6">
                    {{ form_row(AlimentForm.glycemic_index) }}
                    {{ form_row(AlimentForm.glycemic_load) }}
                   
                <h3>Sources</h3>
                <ul class="sources  
                    list-unstyled
                    data-index="{{ AlimentForm.sources|length > 0 ? AlimentForm.sources|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
                    data-prototype="{{ form_widget(AlimentForm.sources.vars.prototype)|e }}"
                    ">
                    <button type="button" class="add_item_link btn btn-success m-3" data-collection-holder-class="sources">Ajouter une source</button>
                </ul>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger m-3">Enregistrer</button>
                    {{ form_end(AlimentForm) }}
            </div>
            </div>
    </section>


 <script src="{{ asset('assets/JS/sources.js') }}" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

the JS script i used

```
const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
    const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

    const item = document.createElement('li');

    item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
        .dataset
        .prototype
        .replace(
        /__name__/g,
        collectionHolder.dataset.index

        );

    collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

    collectionHolder.dataset.index++;
    addsourceFormDeleteLink(item);
    };

    const addsourceFormDeleteLink = (item) => {
        const removeFormButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeFormButton.innerText = 'Supprimer cette source';
        removeFormButton.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "p-2", "my-2");

        item.append(removeFormButton);

        removeFormButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            item.remove();
        });
    }
    document
    .querySelectorAll('.add_item_link')
    .forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection)
    });

    document
        .querySelectorAll('ul.sources li')
        .forEach((source) => {
            addsourceFormDeleteLink(source)
        })
```

My aliment form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Aliment;
use App\Entity\Sources;
use App\Entity\Images;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class AlimentFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(
        FormBuilderInterface $builder,
        array $options
    ): void 
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Nom',
                    'class' => 'form-control w-50 m-auto',
                ],
                'label' => 'Intitulé',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => "Merci d'entrer le nom de l'aliment",
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('glycemic_index', NumberType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'IG',
                    'class' => 'form-control w-50 m-auto',
                ],
                'label' => 'Index glycémique',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => "Merci d'entrer l\'IG de l'aliment",
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('joules', NumberType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'joules',
                    'class' => 'form-control w-50 m-auto',
                ],
                'label' => 'Valeur energétique en joules',
            ])
            ->add('calories', NumberType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'calories',
                    'class' => 'form-control w-50 m-auto',
                ],
                'label' => 'Valeur energétique en calories',
            ])
            
            ->add('glycemic_load', NumberType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Charge glycémique',
                    'class' => 'form-control w-50 m-auto',
                ],
                'label' => 'Charge glycémique',
            ])
           
        $builder->add(
            'sources',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => SourcesFormType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]
           
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Aliment::class,
        ]);
    }
```

What am I supposed to do for having persistance of my sources inot my article?

I tried dd($aliment) to look at the result and received this :

[image]

Comment: in the picture you can see all attributs of my Aliment Table, i choose to delete those who are not accurate.